# for loop on ArrayList change the object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, request

I have a jsp page (says , `MyJspPage.jsp`) -

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<%
    ArrayList<Person> ownerList = (ArrayList<Person>) request
            .getAttribute("ownerList");
    //set again ..
        request.setAttribute("ownerList",ownerList) ;   

%>
</head>
<body>
        <%
            //itr on all the persons ..;
            for (Person person : ownerList) {
        %>
                    // some HTML code.. 
        <%
            }
        %>
            <form action="servlet123" method="POST">
                   // some fields .. 
                   <input type="submit" value="join" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And a servlet  -

```
@WebServlet("/servlet123")
public class servlet123 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get the then set .. 
             ArrayList<Person> ownerList = (ArrayList<Person)request.getAttribute("ownerList"); 
        request.setAttribute("ownerList", ownerList);
             // forward to `MyJspPage.jsp`
            dispather.forward(request, response);
        }

}
```

Firstly another servlet forward to `MyJspPage.jsp` and it work fine , then there is like ping pong between `MyJspPage.jsp` and `servlet123`  . The problem is that when at the 2nd time reachs to `MyJspPage.jsp` it throws an exception -

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error (java.lang.NullPointerException) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

It should be noted that when I omit the for loop from MyJspPage.jsp and change it to be  -

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <%
        ArrayList<Person> ownerList = (ArrayList<Person>) request
                .getAttribute("ownerList");
        //set again ..
            request.setAttribute("ownerList",ownerList) ;   

    %>
    </head>
    <body>
                <form action="servlet123" method="POST">
                       // some fields .. 
                       <input type="submit" value="join" />
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

all the relation between `MyJspPage.jsp` and `servlet123` returns work fine  .

Comment: I'd first check to see if the ownerList is not null, making sure that it's been passed to your page

Comment: Request object is new for each request. You should save and retrieve the list from the session.

Comment: @BheshGurung is there any way to do it on request yet  ?

Comment: Yes - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29

Comment: Request object is created fresh for every submit. Also previous request object is destroyed once the JSP is rendered completely.

Comment: @Kalpak and what happen to the request when move from servlet to jsp ?

Comment: if you are forwarding from servlet to JSP, the request object is carried as is. This does happen in your case. But in the servlet you are accessing the request object for a list which is null. Hence you are passing the same to JSP which when encountered gives you a null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

JSP Code is as follows

---

Instead of setting the arraylist again in the request, you can set it in session as follows
`session.setAttribute("ownerList",ownerList) ;`

You can check for the arraylist to be NOT null before using it in the for loop.

```
        if (ownerList != null)
        {
          for (Person person : ownerList) {
    %>
                // some HTML code.. 
    <%
          }
        }
    %>
```

In the servlet you can write the code as

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 ArrayList<Person> ownerList = (ArrayList<Person)session.getAttribute("ownerList"); 
 request.setAttribute("ownerList", ownerList);
 session.setAttribute("ownerList", null); // toremove unnecessary code from the session
```

There could be other approach also. This one is just closer to the one you chose.